# Sending keystrokes to an application, SendKeys.Send() vs SendMessage()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a simple bot to automate some things in a game. I'm currently sendings commands to the game by bringing the game window to the foreground and sending keys using [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

What I would like to know is, from a detectability point of view, if it's easier for anti cheat engines and such to detect something like this (using [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
public static void SendKeystroke(ushort k)
{
    const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x018;
    const uint SC_CLOSE = 0x053;

    IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "Untitled1 - Notepad++");

    IntPtr result3 = SendMessage(WindowToFind, WM_KEYDOWN, 
                                    ((IntPtr)k), (IntPtr)0);
}

SendKeystroke(Keys.Enter);
```

In the end, the game would receive a keydown event for the enter key nontheless, right?

Comment: It should, any problems here? Maybe better to use `PostMessage` instead.

Comment: @Tony No, no problems. I just want to know if the two examples result in the very same thing, or if #2 can be detected somehow that #1 can't. Why would `PostMessage()` be more useful?

Comment: Experience told me so :) Some times ago I did such a thing to one game and `PostMessage` worked and `SendMessage` - not. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Johan I've tried `Send Keys` while I was trying to achieve it. It works with some games but not with all. It worked with **GTAvc**, But not **GTAsa**

Comment: @Shaharyar Just to clarify; both my examples are working. I just want to know if the latter is easier to detect :)

Comment: I think both methods can be detected if the game engines are using keyboard hooks. In this case they get KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure which contains LLKHF_INJECTED - event injected flag

Comment: @Iale Ok, so you're saying that they're equal (detection-wise)? Is there any way to remove the injected flag programatically?

Comment: @Johan I think so (from that point of view) and there is no way to remove that flag unless you write own keyboard driver

Comment: @Iale Thanks, I appreciate your input

Comment: SendMessage is blocking, if the receiving application doesn't respond to the message the application calling SendMessage will block until it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `SendKeys.Send` typically uses `SendInput`. The alternative method based on journal hooks is not viable with UAC so let us assume that `SendKeys.Send` resolves to `SendInput`.
- `SendMessage` delivers messages direct to the window proc in a synchronous manner.

So, which is easier to detect. Well, for sure the answer is `SendMessage`. These are input messages that arrive at the window procedure without ever having been pulled off the queue with a call to `GetMessage`. That is trivially easy to detect. You simply log some information about the latest message pulled from the queue, and in the window procedure, check the message against the latest queued message.

Now, discriminating between `SendInput` and real human input is probably harder than that. I'm quite sure it's possible though. One way is to install a low-level keyboard hook and look for the LLKHF_INJECTED flag. Harder, but not that much harder.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know anything about whether if both methods gets a ` LLKHF_INJECTED`-flag which can be detected (it's mentioned in the comments)?

Comment: Well, no. SendMessage completely bypasses the message queue. These are not input events at all. So they won't be seen by the keyboard hook.

Comment: Ok. I wonder why it isn't blocked by todays game (that I've tried), since it seems fairly easy to both detect and block. Could it be because that regular keyboard input _sometimes_, under certain circumstances (keyboard layouts, drivers etc), could look similar?

Comment: Perhaps the game authors aren't concerned about fake input

Answer (score 3):

This is a conceptual question as well as technical.

- [**SendKeys.Send()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - is a Windows Forms wrapper for the WinAPI [SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This function works directly with mouse and keyboard input stream. Though there are some limitations(please, read the documentation for this).
- [**SendMessage()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - is a WinAPI function. It is used to send a specific message to a window(s). It can be used to send other messages besides mouse or keyboard input. This is sort of a higher level messaging queue where many other messages get aggregated, to be sent to the window(s). There are also limitations on marshaling messages between processes.
- **Detectability**: this will really depend on how good you can mimic the process of pressing a button and how good the anti-cheat engine is that you are up against. When a human presses a button there is few other messages are send to the window. Besides WM_KEYDOWN, there is WM_KEYUP and some other. Your task is to re-create that sequence as close as possible. You will have to do your own research on this topic. You already can see that human, pressing a button, can not possibly create a situation where only [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is sent to the window, [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must follow up. Also the delay between the two should be humanly possible and so on...

I also believe, SendMessage() may not work as expected with games, because many of them use DirectX DirectInput and in this case the WinAPI SendInput() function, I think, can do a better job as it is a lower level API and works directly with the input stream.

Comment: Thanks. `SendInput()` is working in this game, so that's not an issue. To make the press as human-like as possible, it would be keydown -> keypress -> keyup, right?

Comment: I think the best way to get to know that is to write a small app that can monitor these messages and see for your-self, also read up the descriptions for the messages, if you go that route. I believe keypress is the Windows Forms event, but is not a message.

Comment: Or use Spy++ to see the keyboard messages that go to your window.